# How can I put a Batch program in a HTML5 webpage?

Tags: html, loops, batch-file, ping

I'm new to Stack Overflow, and I have a possibly impossible task that I can't figure out how to do. I am trying to put a DoS `.bat` file on my webpage. I am using [Wix.com](http://wix.com) as my domain provider. My webpage can use `html`, `html5`, and  `.swf` files, but it seems as I can't add PHP. I'm not trying to put a download link, but an interactive batch file. The batch file essentially runs a ping to a server. Here's the code I am using (it's not finished yet though. If you see any mistakes or places where improvements can be made, let me know):

```
            @echo off
            :home
            cls
            @echo off
            title Internet Utilities
            color 0c

            echo devserver) shows statuses of devloper owned servers. type "help_devserver" for more info on this option.

            echo example) shows status of a server set up for examples. type "help_example" for more info on this option.

            echo traceroute) shows the route to the specified server type "help_tracert" for more info on this option.

            echo your server name.com) replace with the name of server you wish to see the status of. This runs a ping in the server you typed in. type "help_ping" for more info on this option.

            echo pingloop) directs you to enter the name of a server to run a "pingloop" on. type "help_pingloop" for more info on this option.

            echo dev) creates a file named "sourcecode.dev" containing the sourcecode of this software. type "help_dev" for more info on this option.

            echo help) directs you to the help menu.

            echo.
                            echo_________________________________________________________________________________________
            set /p servername=Type option or a server name:
            if '%servername%'=='devserver' goto :devserver
            if '%servername%'=='example' goto :example
            if '%servername%'=='traceroute' goto :traceroute
            if '%servername%'=='pingloop' goto :pingloop
            if '%servername%'=='help_devserver' goto :help_devserver
            if '%servername%'=='help_example' goto :help_example
            if '%servername%'=='help_tracrt' goto :help_tracert
            if '%servername%'=='help_ping' goto :help_ping
            if '%servername%'=='help_pingloop' goto :help_pingloop
            if '%servername%'=='help_dev' goto :help_dev
            if '%servername%'=='help' goto :help

            goto :pingserver

            rem if a user enters a servername, they will be directed to :pingserver automatically.

            :help
            cls
            :help_tracrt
            cls
            :help_dev
            cls
            :help_ping
            cls
            :help_example
            cls
            :help_devserver
            cls
            :help_pingloop
            cls

            :pingloop
            cls
            set /p pingloop=Enter the ip or name of server you wish to do a pingloop on:
            echo creating pingloop files

            echo @echo off>>pingloop1.bat
            echo :pingloop>>pingloop1.bat
            echo title Pingloop instance 1 of 4
            echo ping %pingloop%>>pingloop1.bat
            echo goto :pingloop>>pingloop1.bat

            echo pingloop files 1 of 5 created

            echo @echo off>>pingloop2.bat
            echo :pingloop>>pingloop2.bat
            echo title Pingloop instance 2 of 4
            echo ping %pingloop%>>pingloop2.bat
            echo goto :pingloop>>pingloop2.bat

            echo pingloop files 2 of 5 created

            echo @echo off>>pingloop3.bat
            echo :pingloop>>pingloop3.bat
            echo title Pingloop instance 3 of 4>>pingloop3.bat
            echo ping %pingloop%>>pingloop3.bat
            echo goto :pingloop>>pingloop.bat

            echo pingloop files 3 of 5 created

            echo @echo off>>pingloop4.bat
            echo :pingloop>>pingloop4.bat
            echo title Pingloop instance 4 of 4
            echo ping %pingloop%>>pingloop4.bat
            echo goto :pingloop>>pingloop4.bat

            echo pingloop files 4 of 5 created

            echo @echo off>>pingloop_closer.bat
            echo echo closing Pingloops>>pingloop_closer.bat
            echo del pingloop1.bat>>pingloop_closer.bat
            echo del pingloop2.bat>>pingloop_closer.bat
            echo del pingloop3.bat>>pingloop_closer.bat
            echo del pingloop4.bat>>pingloop_closer.bat
            echo del pingloop_closer.bat>>pingloop_closer.bat
            echo taskkill /IM pingloop1.bat /F>>pingloop_closer.bat
            echo taskkill /IM pingloop2.bat /F>>pingloop_closer.bat
            echo taskkill /IM pingloop3.bat /F>>pingloop_closer.bat
            echo taskkill /IM pingloop4.bat /F>>pingloop_closer.bat
            echo exit>>pingloop_closer.bat

            echo starting pingloop. Open pingloop_closer.bat to cancell the pingloops. do not press the red X on the windows
            timeout /t 5
            start pingloop1.bat
            start pingloop2.bat
            start pingloop3.bat
            start pingloop4.bat
            exit

            :example
            cls
            echo Examples of PING reply 
            echo Fri 01/1/2001 01:01:01 Reply from 192.192.192.192: bytes=32 time=8ms TTL=47
            pause

            rem developer server status veiwer from here to end
            rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------
            :devserver
            @echo off
            cls
            echo Preparing PING for required servers. Please wait.
            echo If requested, your token number is %random%%random%%random%.
            timeout /t 3

            rem FTP server checker
            :ftpserver
            cls

            set /p devservername= ftp.ftpdownloadservername.com
            set logfile=%devservername%.data

            for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('ping %host% -n 1 ') do (echo %%A>>%logfile% && GOTO Ping)
            :Ping
            for /f "tokens=* skip=2" %%A in ('ping %devservername% -n 1 ') do (
echo 
            type Log_%devsevername%.log

            rem END OF DEVELOPER SERVER TEST
            rem -----------------------------------------------------------------------

            :pingserver
            cls
            ping %servername%
            echo directing you to home
            pause
            goto home

            :traceroute
            cls
            echo please enter the name of the server you wish to trace a                                route to.
            set /p traceserver=Enter name:
            cls
            tracert %traceserver%
            pause
            rem end of script'
```

Comment: Be careful not to use back ticks (`) as apostrophes (').  They can cause weird formatting problems seen in your post.

Comment: You can't run a Dos bat file in a web page

Comment: Wix.com is a hosting (not domain) provider, and I'm thinking they are likely on UNIX, so DOS is not likely going to work at all.  You might consider bundling your stuff into a PHP script that you run "securely" from a scheduled job on another computer.  Wix.com may offer a scheduling service too...